# Prove 3-torsion in characteristic 2 field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

From washington's book exercise 3.2. I have to show that $E[3] = \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ where $E$ is defined over a characteristic 2 field.

Given the generalized Weierstrauss equation $y^2 + xy = x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_6$ (with $a_4 = 0$), then the point doubling formula is:
$$x_2 = (x_0^4 + a_6) / x_0^2$$
Using the fact that $x(2P) = x(-P)$ for points in $E[3]$, we get that
$$x^4 + x^3 + a_6 = 0$$
So there are 4 possible solution for $x$ in $K^\times$.

Now I just need to prove there are 2 possible values for $y$, and then including the infinity point, we will get a total of 9 points proving the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. This is where I become stuck.

The point doubling formula gives $y_2 = x_1 + y_1$ which after substituting gets:
$$y_2 = x_1 + (y_0 + x_0^2)(x_1 - x_0)/x_0 + y_0$$
Please advise where to proceed from here. Thanks

Comment: Note that you can only put an elliptic curve $E$ over a field of characteristic $2$ in the form you've given if $E$ is *ordinary*. There is still the case where $E$ is supersingular when it can't be written in the form you give. See equations (2a) and (2b) of this paper by Koblitz: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-38424-3_11.pdf